# Generic class as return type

Tags: c#, generics, return-type, idictionary

I have a storage class that uses generics to hold different values.

```
public class Setting<T>
{
    ...
}
```

In another class I want to make a method like

```
  public Setting<T> getSetting(string setting)
  {
        return (Setting<T>)settingDictionary[setting];
  }
```

Where settingDictionary is

```
 private Dictionary<string, object> settingDictionary;
```

I get error:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a way to solve this?
thanks

Comment: You need the class containing getSetting to be generic or make the method generic getSetting<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the method generic:

```
 public Setting<T> GetSetting<T>(string setting)
 {
   // ... Your code...
```

Comment: Damn. Beat to the quick-draw.

Comment: Thanks, this works. If I would want my settingDictionary to hold Setting-objects in stead of object objects, is that possible?

Comment: @NathalieDeCrop If you want to hold any type of `Setting<T>`, you'd need to either make an interface or base class (ie: `ISetting`), or just use object.  If it was only holding a single type of setting, you could make the class generic, but I suspect that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Setting<T>` class doesn't implement [`Dictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) so you should make your method *[`generic type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)* like  `GetSetting<T>`

```
public Setting<T> GetSetting<T>(string setting)
 {

 }
```

Here is a [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/b1e1wj).

Answer (score 0):

Well the compiler does not know what "`T`" is, you can define it as a generic on the method like this:

```
public Setting<T> getSetting<T>(string setting)
```